# Convert Trigger to Class

Tags: apex, trigger, class

```
trigger CalcuContactsonAcc on Contact (After insert, After Delete, After Undelete, After Update) {

  Set<Id> setAccountIds = new Set<Id>();

if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUndelete){
for(Contact con : Trigger.new){
if(con.AccountID != Null)
setAccountIds.add(con.AccountId);
}
}

if(Trigger.isDelete){
for(Contact con : Trigger.old){
if(con.AccountID != Null)
setAccountIds.add(con.AccountId);
}
}

if(Trigger.isUpdate){
for(Contact con : Trigger.old){
if(con.AccountID != Null){
setAccountIds.add(con.AccountId);
}
if(Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId != null)
setAccountIds.add(Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId);
}
}

List<Account> listAccs = [SELECT id,name,number_of_contacts__c ,(Select id from contacts Where Level__c='Primary') FROM Account WHERE Id in : setAccountIds];
for(Account acc :listAccs){
acc.number_of_contacts__c = acc.contacts.size();
}
update listAccs;

}
```

Can you please tell me how to make it as separate helper class and trigger?

Comment: you could first a create a helper class and pass trigger context variable as an argument to that method

Comment: Hi Santanu Thank you for your response,But I am new to Coding and I am Confused with this,Can you please give me example for above trigger

Comment: refer this trailhead https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_basics_dotnet/units/execution_context

Comment: if(Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId != null)
setAccountIds.add(Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId);
}                                                                                                                                                 Can you please suggest me logic in class for above lines thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Responding here as per comment**

During update you need to compare old AccountId with new one. If there is a change then you need to store both the accountIds to calculate the count of contacts.

Correct logic will be as follows:

```
if(Trigger.isUpdate){
    for(Contact con : Trigger.new){
        if(con.AccountID != null && con.AccountID != Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId){
            setAccountIds.add(con.AccountId);
            setAccountIds.add(Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId);
        }
        if(Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId == null && con.AccountID !=null)
        {
            setAccountIds.add(con.AccountId);
        }
    }
}
```

Refer [Understand Execution Context](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_basics_dotnet/units/execution_context) trailhead to prepare trigger handler